# How to create a flip card with css3 in Internet explorer?

Tags: html, css

I have created a flip card with css3. It is working fine in chrome but not in IE. How to do in IE?

On hovering, Card should flip and show other content on the back side.In order to achieve I have created two class- front and back. It is working fine in chrome but not in Internet explorer.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</style>
</head>


<h1>Card Flip with Text</h1>
<h3>Hover over the image below:</h3>

<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_avatar3.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version of IE? Microsoft hasn't been actively developing IE for several years so you shouldn't expect parity with Chrome. In cases like this https://caniuse.com is your friend. For example `transform-style: preserve-3d` isn't supported in ANY version of IE. You'll need to find a polyfill or create the effect another way.